Grails UrlMappings - access params and custom vars within a constraint validator
Is there a way to access request parameters or custom variables within a constraint validator in UrlMappings?
For example:
"/stuff/$scope/$feature" ( controller: 'stuff' ) {
  customVar = 'hello'
  constraints { feature(validator: { MyUtils.validateFeatureByScope(scope, it) }) }
}

I checked the source code for Grails’ unified validation constraints, and I could not find a solution out-of-the-box.
Thanks in advance for any suggestion!
